# In Apache hadoop 2.x. Does the current UserGroupInformation lose credentials in a child thread?

Tags: authentication, hadoop, hadoop2, usergroups

Here is the simple experiment I used to demonstrate the problem, written in scala, with Hadoop 2.7.7 as the only dependency:

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation

import scala.concurrent.duration.{Duration, MINUTES}
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}

object UGITest {
        val ugi = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser
        val credential = ugi.getCredentials

        val ff = Future {

          val _ugi = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser
          val _credential = _ugi.getCredentials

          require(ugi == _ugi, s"UGI is lost, before: $ugi, now ${_ugi}")

          require(credential == _credential, s"credential is lost, before: $credential, now ${_credential}")

        }(ExecutionContext.global)

        Await.result(ff, Duration.apply(1, MINUTES))
}
```

The first requirement `ugi==_ugi` passed successfully, indicating that closure of the `Future` was successfully launched in a child thread.

The second requirement `credential==_credential` fail with the following information:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: credential is lost, before: org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials@cb6e68f, now org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials@6b746674
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
    at ...
```

It appears that the same UserGroupInformation is used, but all credentials are lost. What's the purpose of this design?

The above experiment was just executed on a single computer not in any cluster. I have't tested it with any hadoop authentication framework (e.g. kerberos) enabled. But I think the result will be more or less the same.

Comment: `credentials` are objects that provide access to keys and tokens. Objects can't be compared for equality using `==`.

Comment: In scala, the operator == is overloaded to be equivalent to Java's `equals()`. But one way or the other, should credentials granted to a thread automatically applies to its child thread?

Comment: `org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials` inherit `equals` implementation from `java.lang.Object` i.e. same object reference. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/security/Credentials.html It doesnt compare actual keys and tokens inside those objects.

Comment: @mazaneicha, thanks a lot. This should apply to `Subject` as well. However I'm still curious about the purpose of this design (and by extension, how to bypass it, thus ensure that the Future has the same privilege with the parent thread)